# How to convert Python threading code to multiprocessing code?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, gil

I need to convert a `threading` application to a `multiprocessing` application for multiple reasons (GIL, memory leaks). Fortunately the threads are quite isolated and only communicate via `Queue.Queue`s. This primitive is also available in `multiprocessing` so everything looks fine. Now before I enter this minefield I'd like to get some advice on the upcoming problems:

1. How to ensure that my objects can be transfered via the `Queue`? Do I need to provide some `__setstate__`?
2. Can I rely on `put` returning instantly (like with `threading` `Queue`s)?
3. General hints/tips?
4. Anything worthwhile to read apart from the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html)?

Comment: Initializing database connections in `subclass(Process).__init__` *is* a problem. :-/

Comment: another user recently rewrote my threaded example with the multiprocessing library.  i was using queue as well.  might be worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072816/ideal-thread-structure-question-involves-multiple-thread-communication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to part 1:

Everything that has to pass through a `multiprocessing.Queue` (or `Pipe` or whatever) has to be [picklable](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). This includes basic types such as `tuple`s, `list`s and `dict`s. Also classes are supported if they are top-level and not too complicated (check the details). Trying to pass `lambda`s around will fail however.

Answer to part 2:

A `put` consists of two parts: It takes a semaphore to modify the queue and it optionally starts a feeder thread. So if no other `Process` tries to `put` to the same `Queue` at the same time (for instance because there is only one `Process` writing to it), it should be fast. For me it turned out to be fast enough for all practical purposes.

Partial answer to part 3:

- The plain `multiprocessing.queue.Queue` lacks a `task_done` method, so it cannot be used as a drop-in replacement directly. (A subclass provides the method.)
- The old `processing.queue.Queue` lacks a `qsize` method and the newer `multiprocessing` version is inaccurate (just keep this in mind).
- Since filedescriptors normally inherited on `fork`, care needs to be taken about closing them in the right processes.